# Naive bayes algorithm using python3.5.2

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to implement naive bayes algorithm in a dataset using python 3.5.2 but it is giving me a error:

> ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Can anyone help me in this issue? I am very new to python.

```
import csv
import nltk
import nltk.classify.util
from nltk.classify import NaiveBayesClassifier
f = open("C:\Python_code\pima-indians-diabetes.csv")
csv_f = csv.reader(f)
import numpy
csv_f = numpy.random.rand(100, 5)
numpy.random.shuffle(csv_f)
training, test = csv_f[:80,:], csv_f[80:,:]
print(training,test)
classifier = nltk.NaiveBayesClassifier.train(training)
print("Naive Bayes Algo Accuracy:", (nltk.classify.accuracy(classifier,test))*100)
```

Comment: What line raises the error?

Comment: classifier = nltk.NaiveBayesClassifier.train(training)
    print("Naive Bayes Algo Accuracy:",     (nltk.classify.accuracy(classifier,test))*100)                                                                           this lines raises the error

Comment: It looks like you feed the classifier with incorrect data. Try to check the input of `nltk.NaiveBayesClassifier.train` and compare it with your variable `training`.

Comment: I have tried replacing the last 2 line with the following code                                                   from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
clf = GaussianNB()
clf.fit(features_training,labels_training)
pred = clf.predict(features_test)
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
print (accuracy_score(pred,labels_test))                                                                 but it is giving me NameError: name 'features_training' is not defined

Comment: @Fomalhaut can you please explain what you have said.

Comment: All you need is to create the input correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Read the documentation how to use `nltk.NaiveBayesClassifier` correctly: http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/classify/naivebayes.html

You should prepare the correct input for `train`. It's a list of tuples `(featureset, label)`.